# Eagerly loading nested associations, belongs_to, and has_one through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my app students do problems in either problem_sets or quizzes.  When a student does a problem on a problem set, for instance, two stats are updated on that problem/user - a problem_set_stat and a problem_stat.  Accordingly my relations are as follows

```
class ProblemSetInstance
    has_one :user
    has_many :problem_set_stats
end

class ProblemSetStat
    belongs_to :problem_set
    belongs_to :problem_stat
    has_one    :problem_type, :through => :problem_stat
end

class ProblemStat
    belongs_to :problem_type
    # no has_many problem_set_stats, because I never need to access them from here currently
end
```

I ran into a curious thing when trying to optimize some database queries.  When I'm displaying the problem set I use the following query

```
ps = problem_set_stats.includes(:problem_stat => [:problem_type])
```

now, I can do `ps.first.problem_stat` and `ps.first.problem_stat.problem_type` without executing additional queries.  However, when I do `ps.first.problem_type` it DOES do another query.  Any way to fix this without changing all of my `.problem_type`s to `.problem_stat.problem_type`s?

Comment: Have you tried eagerloading the has_one objects as well? `problem_set_stats.includes([:problem_stat => [:problem_type], :problem_type])`

Comment: Thanks! That gives me a syntax error, but the nearly identical `problem_set_stats.includes(:problem_stat => [:problem_type]).includes(:problem_type)` works, and generates the same exact queries!

Comment: sorry for the syntax error. I just added an answer and fixed the syntax. You can do it within a single `includes` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not eager-loading the has_one relationship in that case is because it's defined as a separate relationship on your model. Each relationship is independent, so even through it's "through" another relationship, you will still need to explicitly include it.

```
problem_set_stats.includes({:problem_stat => :problem_type}, :problem_type)
```